# Why does javax MimeType not implement equals?

Tags: java

The [javax.activation.MimeType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimeType.html) class does not compare intuitively (to me) due to a lack of an overridden `equals`-method. Consider the following snippet;

```
MimeType a = new MimeType("image/png");
MimeType b = new MimeType("image/png");

a.equals(b);                            // false

a.toString().equals(b.toString());      // true
a.getBaseType().equals(b.getBaseType());// true
a.getSubType().equals(b.getSubType());  // true
a.getParameters().size();               // 0
b.getParameters().size();               // 0
```

It seems to me that `a` and `b` are equal in every aspect and that `a.equals(b)` should return `true`.

Is there a reason that this class does not implement an `equals`-method?

Update: There exists a [`match`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimeType.html#match(javax.activation.MimeType))-method which does exactly what I want, but I only found out after posting this question which kind-of confirms the not-so-intuitiveness of this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speculate as this decision is not documented, but when checking the `MimeType` class, there are two match methods: `match(MimeType)` and `match(String)`. The second does it's job by constructing a `MimeType` object from the string argument and then calling the first `match` method.

So by implementing the match methods, it is possible to compare to MimeType and String objects. This would not be possible by implementing the `equals(Object)`method. Of course you could implement the `equals` method so that it can compare to both a `MimeType` and a `String`, but this would violate the contract that is specified by the `equals`documentation:

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

This would only work if `String.equals(Object o)` would use `o.toString()` to do the comparison, but `String` doc states:

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

So you could only implement `equals` to compare to a different `MimeType`, and if you want to compare to a `String`, you would have to fall back to the `match(String)` method.

And I think the reason for not implementing `equals` in this class is just to keep the method you use for comparing consistent for different objects to compare to.

Comment: You're correct that it would be wrong for `.match(String)` to instead be named `.equals(String)`, or for `.equals(Object)` to compare `String` values as equal, but that has nothing to do with implementing `.equals()`. It would be perfectly reasonable to correctly implement `MimeType.equals(Object)` *in addition to* the existing `.match()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider filing a bug; at a glance this seems like a class that should properly override `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`. Of course that won't help you for some time (not sure if this library is on the JDK's release cycle).

As a workaround you could create a subclass or wrapper class that properly implements `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`, e.g.:

```
public class ValueMimeType extends MimeType {
  // constructors

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o instanceof ValueMimeType) { // not MimeType, as that wouldn't be symetric
      return match((ValueMimeType) o);
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return toString().hashCode();
  }
}
```

And just always use `ValueMimeType` instead of `MimeType`. Obviously not ideal, but better than nothing.

Comment: Indeed, bug has been filed: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236541